# Unable to download Javascript from remote installation (Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, openshift

I installed my CI application on a remote server (an OpenShift install). I have Javascript files included in the view headers. When I try to access the application, all the Javascript files are stuck in "GET" (looking at firebug Net console) and spin endlessly. Am I missing some specification? Here is an example of what I have in the view header file within the head tags

```
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery-1.8.2.js');?>"type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Thanks!

Mmiz

Comment: What is the output in the src attribute? And does it point to the correct URL?

Comment: check the GET request URL on your firebug console, and double check that this the expected value. Probably you need to check the base_url config constant on /application/config/config.php

Comment: @Repox: If I cut-n-paste the src attribute (see below) - it correctly displays the jquery file on the remote system. src="http://xxx.rhcloud.com/js/jquery-1.8.2.js - So I'm somewhat stumped!

Comment: @Iraklis - Same thing here - the Get request URL also displays the file correctly if I cut-n-paste it. Damn. I had high hopes on this one. I'll fiddle with the base_url and see if it does anything positive.

Comment: @user1072910 And pasting the URL in your browser gives you the script?

Comment: Well thanks to both of you I figured it out by staring at the URLs till it finally dawned on me - my base_url was http://xxxxx - when I changed it to https it all worked. Wish it had struck me earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the base_url in applications/config needed to specify https instead of http: which is what I had. This might be an OpenShift deployment thing but it did solve my problem!